# Scala import confusion

Tags: scala

I am using `breeze`, a general package in `scala`, and I also created a package named `breeze`, under which I created an object called `Utils`.

So I can

`import breeze.linalg._`(which is **default package**)

but failed to

`import breeze.Utils._`(which is **self-defined**)

> ... not a member of breeze...

I guess `scala` get confused when import, how to solve the conflict?

Structure is:

```
src/
 └─ main/
     └─ scala/
         └─ breeze/
             ├─ BreezeTest.scala (contains object BreezeTest)
             ├─ kmeansTest.sc
             ├─ test.sc
             ├─ testMat.sc
             └─ Utils.scala (contains object Utils)
```

Comment: How did you declared your own `breeze` package?, from where does it fails to import? - please share a [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including folder structure, build tool used, scala version, and anything you find useful to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What file is the import statement in?

Comment: Also, did you put "package breeze" in the Utils.scala file?

Comment: I import breeze.Utils in test.sc

Comment: What about my second question? Does Utils have a package declaration?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The answer is yes. The top of Utils is package breeze. (but it is my self-defined breeze)